# How to deal with too small numbers

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

When dealing with a code that produces too small numbers (in a complicated way) like

```
0.33691 4.015757066049965*10^-330
```

I get the following warning

> General::munfl: 0.00530878/1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

Is there any tricky way to ensure that too small resulting numbers in my function are well handled by MMA (12.1)?

Note that I had a look at General::munfl and tried some proposed ideas (e.g `SetPrecision`, `Rationalize`,..), but I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you. Done!

Comment: Do you have any idea on my question?

Comment: `SetPrecision[ 0.33691 4.015757066049965*10^-300, $MachinePrecision] 10^-30` works, but to say more I would need to know how you generated this number and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The problem is that the numbers are generated in complex way (result of several steps), let's say that we have instead of the mentioned number, an abstract number x<\$MinMachineNumber. Can we build a function that do the same trick you did but for an input $x$?

Comment: I recommend that you add to your question a simple version  of your code that still produces an underflow.  Then, perhaps readers can provide useful answers.  In the meantime, consider `x = SetPrecision[1.1 10^-10, $MachinePrecision]` followed by `x^400`.  The point is, you need to set the `Precision` appropriately before the underflow occurs, not after.